# Flutter change StaggeredGridView crossAxisCount by screen rotation

Tags: flutter

`StaggeredGridView` like with `GridView` support `crossAxisCount` and that work fine when i define specific number for `crossAxisCount`, such as `1` or `2`
for this option i want to change that with screen size resolution automatically by code, for example this below code can calculate screen size and can be used for `GridView` or `StaggeredGridView`

```
int _crossAxisCount = 0;
final double screenWidthSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
if (screenWidthSize > 720) {
  _crossAxisCount = 3;
} else if (screenWidthSize > 520) {
  _crossAxisCount = 2;
} else {
  _crossAxisCount = 1;
}
```

when i define `_crossAxisCount` for the library `crossAxisCount` option, it doesn't work and only work when i press on hot reload button

but when i change that to specific count, that work fine

**UPDATED:**

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder:(context,constraints){
    int _crossAxisCount = 0;
    final double screenWidthSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    if (screenWidthSize > 720) {
      _crossAxisCount = 3;
    } else if (screenWidthSize > 520) {
      _crossAxisCount = 2;
    } else {
      _crossAxisCount = 1;
    }
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      primary: false,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: _crossAxisCount ,
      mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
      itemCount: feedsList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              BuildFeedsItems(
                  item: feedsList[index] as FeedsItemsList,
                  doubleTapImageEvents: _doubleTapImageEvents,
                  fullScreenDialog: fullScreenDialog,
                  theme: theme )
            ],
          )),
      staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => const StaggeredTile.fit(1),
    );
  },
)
```

how can help me to know whats this issue and how can i fix that?

Comment: where you are calculating screenWidthSize and _crossAxisCount ?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya in build method

Comment: your question is very much unclear, is this a hot reload issue? or a programming  issue?

Comment: @iamyadunandan multiple rows when i hot reload work fine, but when restart application it doesn't work and i have 1 column in one side of screen

Comment: Log width when you hot reload and after restart.. Does it out put the same result?

Comment: I am sorry but your error is not reproducible. Please consider improving your question with logs or further code to get an answer.

Comment: Try to put your `StaggeredGridView` inside `LayoutBuilder`, and also calculate `crossAxisCount` inside builder

Comment: @DimaRostopira unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: can you mention how you are testing mean do you want to change grid count when orientation change? any screen have only fixed width so it will not change grid count. can you clear your desire output more.

Answer (score 0):

Get the screen orientation from the `MediaQuery` and set the `crossAxisCount` depending on the orientation.

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
   ...
   crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape ? 4 : 2,
   ...
)
```

Comment: my problem is calculating screen size and divide that to some part not orientation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OrientaionBuilder` in this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation#2-use-an-orientationbuilder-to-change-the-number-of-columns)

Example:

```
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return GridView.count(
      // Create a grid with 2 columns in portrait mode,
      // or 3 columns in landscape mode.
      crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: my problem is calculating screen size and divide that to some part not orientation, thanks

Comment: So you should consider using `LayoutBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _crossAxisCount = 0;
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context,constraints){
        if(constraints.maxWidth>720){
            _crossAxisCount = 3;
            return _straggeredView(_crossAxisCount);
        }else if(constraints.maxWidth>520 && constraints.maxWidth<720){
            _crossAxisCount = 2;
            return _straggeredView(_crossAxisCount);
        }else{
            _crossAxisCount = 1;
            return _straggeredView(_crossAxisCount);
        }
      },
    )
}

Widget _straggeredView(_crossAxisCount) {
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
       crossAxisCount : _crossAxisCount,
      ...
    )
  }
```